# has_many through belongs_to with a has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through, has-many

This is what I want to achive:

```
class Foo
  belongs_to :bar
  has_many :foos, trough: :bar, class_name: 'Foo'
end

class Bar
  has_many :Foo
end
```

Is this possible without a jointable? Tried different combinations of class_name and source options to the has_many through but no success so far. Either I get stuck on a source not found even-though it was provided or I ends up in a mysterious `No block given` error.  Even tried to delegate from `:bar` to `:foo`.

Maingoal: `Foo.first.foos` as relation

Maybe someone can enlighten me if its even possible, when yes: how?

best regards

Comment: you need records like this: Class_A.first.Class_B.Class_As ??

Comment: what problem to you try to solve?

Comment: I am not sure why you need this, you can get these details easily by a.b.a or just create a scope or method

Comment: Sorry bout late reply. It has to be a relation, since we use this in a generic generated custom json that gets resolved by some angularjs app. So unfortunately it has to be like this. So it needs to resolve to something like this Foo.first.foos.

Answer (score 3):

`source` works fine.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar
  has_many :placeholder, through: :bar, source: :foo
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foo
end
```

Which Rails version do you use?

Comment: updated my question with more clear class names. Unfortunately it doesnt work with source, it complains with `No block given`